change kea dhcp server config without reloading it
I'm using kea dhcp and I'm trying to change a existing subnet while it's running. I wrote a demo in C using curl to send "config-set" and "config-reload" command to the ctrl agent. But it didn't work.
For example , I run the server then I change the kea-dhcp4.conf and save it, then I run the demo.In the demo, I first use "config-get" to get currnet config and print the "pools", then I use "config-reload" and I print the "pools" again after that.The result is:
Subnet: "pool": "192.168.0.130-192.168.0.150"
[ { "result": 0, "text": "Configuration applied successfully." } ]
Subnet: "pool": "192.168.0.130-192.168.0.150"
It tells that it's successful but actually nothing change, what should i do?
Btw can somebody tell me how to use "config-set" correctly, i can't find the correct format of this command.
